# Condition Index for continuous and categorical variables using perturb package

Tags: r, glmnet

I try to asses if there is a multicollinearity between the independent variables for a logistic regression problem.
In doing so, I learned that the perturb package in R would be a good choice. 
I have tried the examples in the vignette

```
library(perturb)
library(glmnet)
data(consumption)
ct1 <- with(consumption, c(NA,cons[-length(cons)]))  #evaluate a condition
m1 <- lm(cons ~ ct1+dpi+rate+d_dpi, data = consumption)
cd<-colldiag(m1, center=T)
cd
```

and noticed the following:

1. `colldiag` provides a nice output for Cond. index and variance Decomposition.  One can easily figure out which are the var. that might cause the issue. But, it is implemented only for continuous variable. 
   Trying to add a categorical one, it crashed:

   ```
   library(car)
   data(Duncan)
   attach(Duncan)
   m2<-lm(prestige~income+education+type, data=Duncan)
   colldiag(m2)
   ```

   > "Error in v^2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator".

   Do I have to explicitly code the categorical one (`type`) into dummy var in oder to use `colldiag` or is `colldiag` meant to work indeed only for continuous var?
2. The perturb function seems to solve this issue when running the code above but the output is completely different and I don't know how to read/interpret it since I don't see any Condition number in the summary.

   ```
   p2<- perturb(m2,pvars=c("income","education"),prange=c(1,1),pfac=list("type",pcnt=95))
   summary(p2)
   ```

   Does anybody has an idea on how to get a meaning out of this?
   The final goal for my analysis is actualy to asses multicolinearity for a mixt of continuous and categorical var using condition index.